# How to fill a textfield on clickEvent?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, fullcalendar

I'm using `jQuery` `Full Calendar` and trying to fill a textfield on a `clickEvent`
with the hour of the event.

`time` is the name of the attribute in my `Event` model.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                  eventClick: function() {

                            // set value?
                        $('#time').val("<%= @event.time %>");


                        }
    })

});
```

HTML source:

```
<article class="blog-post margin-60">
<div id="calendar" class="fc fc-ltr">
<table class="fc-header" style="width:100%">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="fc-header-left">
<span class="fc-header-title"><h2>Oct 20 — 24 2014</h2></span>
</td>
<td class="fc-header-center"></td>
<td class="fc-header-right">
<span class="fc-button fc-button-today fc-state-default fc-corner-left fc-corner-right fc-state-disabled" unselectable="on">today</span>
<span class="fc-header-space"></span>
<span class="fc-button fc-button-prev fc-state-default fc-corner-left" unselectable="on"><span class="fc-text-arrow">‹</span></span><span class="fc-button fc-button-next fc-state-default fc-corner-right" unselectable="on">
<span class="fc-text-arrow">›</span></span></td></tr></tbody></table><div class="fc-content" style="position: relative;"><div class="fc-view fc-view-basicWeek fc-grid" style="position:relative" unselectable="on">
<div class="fc-event-container" style="position:absolute;z-index:8;top:0;left:0">
<div class="fc-event fc-event-hori fc-event-start fc-event-end" style="position: absolute; left: 3px; width: 147px; top: 24px;">
<div class="fc-event-inner"><span class="fc-event-title">08:00:00</span></div>
</div>
<div class="fc-event fc-event-hori fc-event-start fc-event-end" style="position: absolute; left: 3px; width: 147px; top: 47px;">
...
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Perhaps you have to format the time to a format that JS understands.

Comment: How does the generated javascript look in the browser?

Comment: @Albin I added the HTML.

Comment: I meant the script tag generated by your "event.js.erb" or whatever it is called

Answer (score 0):

```
eventClick: function(event) {
    $('#time').val(event.start);
}
```

See [eventClick](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/mouse/eventClick/) and [Event_Object](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Object/) for reference. Basically you use the javascript event object you've passed in. You will need to do some processing to get the hour, but that shouldn't be too difficult.